# Testing higher order functions in scala

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I have a case where I have a list of rules that can disqualify a particular item (a command). Each of the rules is a high order function. (For reusability).

At the end I need to verify what rule caused the failure. How can I identify what rule caused the failure?

Is there a way that I can get the function name for where the function came from?

When I'm testing and I return back the function that caused the failure I'm getting a non-descriptive "" which doesn't correlate to what is actually returned.

An example of this:

```
   object Library { 
       def testIf5(v:Int): Boolean = { v==5} 
   }

   class CommandVerifier { 
      def doesItFail(value: Int, rules: List[(Int)=>Boolean]) {
           rules.find(r=> !r(value))
      }

   }

   val expected = testIf5
   val actaul = new CommandVerifier().doesItFail(5, List(testIf5))
   actual should be expected (expected)
```

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about what you mean by "verify" and "identify"?  Verify and identify in what way?

Comment: In the example I'm trying to do a comparison against the function that i expect to have been returned and what it actually was. I want to be able to make the comparision there.

Comment: Also, it appears in my IDE it thinks the return type of `.doesItFail` when assigning it to `actaul` thinks it is `Unit`. Try specifying the return type to be `Option[(Int) => Boolean]`. `def doesItFail(value: Int, rules: List[(Int)=>Boolean]): Option[(Int) => Boolean] = {
    rules.find(r => !r(value))
  }`

Comment: Also, if you want the function name at runtime, that won't be possible since functions don't have names at runtime. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408880/scala-get-function-name-that-was-sent-as-param and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790311/how-do-i-get-the-function-name-in-scala. I think you should be testing these rules independently.

Comment: That sounds like the answer right there.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll put it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the function name at runtime, that won't be possible since functions don't have names at runtime. See [scala get function name that was sent as param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408880/scala-get-function-name-that-was-sent-as-param) and [How do I get the function name in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790311/how-do-i-get-the-function-name-in-scala). I think you should be testing these rules independently